# Where in a project does Unity associate Image names with their source files?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm looking at the source code for a Unity project I just started collaborating on.  I can't find where in the project Unity associates a filename with an `Image` object referred to in the C# scripts. (I'm completely new to Unity)

The game runs fine, so I know Unity is able to load the images, and there are multiple places in the C# scripts that refer to specific Images, but I can't find any place in the scripts that define what file an `Image` is loaded from (something like `public Image sprite1 = loadImage("art.png");`).

These sprites were imported through the Unity editor, so I'm not sure if Unity associated these Images with filenames somewhere in the project itself, in some non-human-readable file, or in Unity's program files (ie, outside of version control).

My main concern is that any changes I make to these sprites won't be reflected in version control, since there may be some crucial relationships defined outside of any tracked files.

Answer (score 1):

Image references are generally handled by the drag and drop system, objects with scripts on them either in the scene view or in prefabs will have references to things like images set up via the Unity GUI.

Try using the searchbar and typing in the exact name to your image, from this should pull all gameobjects in your scene and all prefabs in your project that reference it.

**Some extra background on how this works:** (you don't need to know this, but it's handy)

Unity parses all content files it detects and assigns them a .meta file which contains a unique GUID that unity uses to track and reference that particular asset. Other meta files associated with prefabs and scenes will have that guid internally to keep a reference to that particular asset. This makes it vitally important to make sure you check in changed .meta files! They aren't generated local files, they're extremely important!

Unity Plugins for handling version control in unity should automatically check out files that change those references, generally it's pretty foolproof. Doing something as simple as renaming or moving a file will preserve the internal guid, so it's totally safe (just remember to rename and move files *inside* the unity editor! You can relocate files externally, just make sure you don't lose the .meta file)

Comment: Actually, if you open up the .scene file in Notepad, you will see all the game object, components,  connections and value. This is why, you should always move assets within Unity editor (not file explorer) so those connections keep getting updated properly.  The .scene is written in yaml so you it is not too hard to read and knowing your scene, you'll just figure out what is what. You can witness the Unity serialization process.

Answer (score 0):

Unity references images by means of GUID, that is assigned to an imported file on import, and saved to an invisible .meta file. AS long as you change both image filename and its corresponding .meta filename, and keep the GUID, unity will keep the reference, regardless of the actual file name (as long as you keep the GUID).

Important takeway is that you should never loose your .meta files (make sure they are tracked by your version control), as if you do, unity will generate a new random GUID for that file, and the relationship will never be restored back, which can be pretty catastrophic for a project.

Of course this does not apply to the images loaded in runtime, referenced by filenames.